# Is a loss function the flip side of a coin to a utility function, or are they not related?

Tags: probability, loss-functions, decision-theory

I'm trying to get a grasp on utility and loss functions, and at first I thought that a utility function was the flipside of a loss function and vice versa. Kind of like how if you know the probability of getting heads is p, you know the probability of getting tails (1-p). However, I can't find anything on the internet to that effect. I might be thinking of the regret function, but I'm not sure. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct, the loss function is the negative of the utility function. In optimization we either maximize the utility or minimize the loss, but that's just a choice of convention, the optimization is mathematically equivalent.

Comment: I don't think it's universally true. They're certainly related though

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything; to the extent that you can specify utility, the loss function should be chosen so that minimizing the loss maximizes the utility.

Answer (score 12):

Loss is a negative utility. If you need an authoritative source for this, check the *Statistical Decision Theory* book by James O. Berger (p. 53):

> Once $U(\theta, a)$ has been obtained, the loss function can simply be
>   defined as
>
> $$ L(\theta, a) = -U(\theta, a). \tag{2.3} $$

The same is stated by Christian P. Robert in his book *The Bayesian Choice*, who introduces utility with the following notion (p. 54):

> The notion of utility (defined as the opposite of loss) is used not
>   only in Statistics, but also in Economics and in other fields like
>   Game Theory where it is necessary to order consequences of actions or
>   decisions. Consequences (or rewards) are generic notions which
>   summarize the set of outcomes resulting from the decision-maker’s
>   action. In the simplest cases, it may be the monetary profit or loss
>   resulting from the decision. (...)

Answer (score 3):

$U(x)=-\mathcal{L}(x)$.  I cannot imagine you will find anything on the internet.  I believe you can find a formal treatment of these functions in Geweke's "Contemporary Bayesian Econometrics and Statistics."

Comment: We could perhaps be more general than that. I think some other choice of $\mathcal L$ such that minimizing it will maximize $U$ should suffice. That includes $U = -\mathcal{L}$ but really, $U=m(-\mathcal{L})$ for some sufficiently nice monotonic function $m$ should work just as well.  (would continuity of $m$ suffice? Is it more than required? It would at least be desirable to have it, for several reasons). It's a bit like maximizing likelihood vs log-likelihood vs 2 log likelihood -- the negative of any of them could be taken as a loss function (any many other choices beside)