# -2 in the gradient of the loss function

Tags: gradient-descent, loss-functions, reinforcement-learning

I'm reading [Humman-level control through deep reinforcement learning](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf)
, at the beginning of Page 7, it defines a loss function (I omit some parameters to make it cleaner)
$$
L(\theta)=\mathbf E\left[\left(r+\gamma \max_{a'}\hat Q(s', a';\theta^-)-Q(s, a;\theta)\right)^2\right]
$$
Then I differentiate it with respect to the weights, I get
$$
\nabla_\theta  L(\theta)=\mathbf E\left[-2\left(r+\gamma \max_{a'}Q(s', a'; \theta^-)-Q(s, a;\theta)\right)\nabla_\theta Q(s, a;\theta)\right]
$$
It is not consistent with the gradient in the paper. (my version has $-2$). What's wrong with my inference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the paper is only interested in finding the zeros of the gradient?  In that case it would be unconcerned about any constant nonzero multiple.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for commenting. And sorry that I'm not so sure about what you meant, could you be more specific? Why is the paper only interested in finding the zeros of the gradient? IMHO, $\nabla_\theta L(\theta)$ is going to be used to update $\theta$, and zero seems meaningless in that case.

Comment: @SherwinChen It's quite common in statistics that we ignore the constant for differentiation. The paper is right. whuber is correct.

Comment: @SmallChess Thanks, so that's just a convention?

Comment: I changed your title to something more descriptive, feel free to edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said by others in the comments, such constants are often ignored, as they don't influence the result of minimizing the loss. So squared loss is often defined as $\tfrac{1}{2} (x-y)^2$, so that $\tfrac{1}{2} $ cancels out with $2$ and you don't have to bother with it. I'd guess that's also the case in here. The sign is only for the optimization algorithm, since some of them specialize in minimizing, while other in maximizing. You minimize the loss, or maximize negative loss (i.e. [utility](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/263463/35989)).

Comment: I agree with you about the $2$ part, but what confuses me is the negative sign, I think it becomes important when doing gradient ascent/descent. so why should we ignore that?

Comment: @SherwinChen the sign is only for your optimization algorithm, since some of them specialize in minimizing things, while other in maximizing. You minimize the loss, or maximize negative loss (or utility).